# Is there a Mobile SDK for IBM Cloud Storage?

Tags: android, ios, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services, ibm-cloud-tools

We plan to integrate IBM Cloud Storage into our iOS and Android applications. Does anybody know if there is an SDK available for this, like Amazon s3?

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Object Storage Android and Swift SDK here:

**Swift:**

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bluemix-objectstorage-clientsdk-swift

**Android:**

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bluemix-objectstorage-clientsdk-android

Comment: Thank You for your Quick Reply. is Objective C library not available?

Comment: You can actually use a Swift SDK in an Objective-C project.

Comment: Also, it might be useful to read this: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloud-object-storage-s3-api-intro/

Answer (score 0):

It will be late but the SDK posted by @joe are deprecated. Here is the official link for all the SDK's of different technologies.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cloud-cli-sdk